# Zoom to cursor in photoshop, using extendscript or basil.js

Tags: javascript, photoshop, basil.js

Programmatically, is there a way to zoom in to the last clicked position in Photoshop, CS6, either with extendscript's JavaScript or with basil.j?  The reference to basil.j (http://basiljs.ch/reference/) refers to b.atan2(y, x) and atan2 and may indicate that either functions might be aware of the position of the cursor, or the last place clicked on a photo in Photoshop?  On the other hand, I am not sure basil.j works with Photoshop?
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Basil.js is specifically for InDesign

Comment: OK. Thanks.  Have you developed ways of letting the user zoom in and/or pan, and perhaps even after a mouse click?

Comment: No sorry. I suggest looking through the photoshop scripting guide https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html